# Passing multiple value from MVC3 View to an ActionMethod

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wonder if anybody can help me here.  I apologise for sounding like a thicko but I'm new to MVC3 and I'm trying to pass 2 values from a view to an action method but it just isn't playing fair!

HTML:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ASSIGN", "AssignTokenToDataTemplate", "HostHtmlTokenManager", 
new { htmlTokenId = item.Id }, new { htmlDataTemplateId = 1 })
```

ACTION METHOD:

```
public ActionResult AssignTokenToDataTemplate(int htmlTokenId, int htmlDataTemplateId)
{
    // Do some database stuff here
    return View("AssignAnExistingTokenToHtmlDataTemplate", new {templateId = htmlDataTemplateId});
}
```

I want to pass two integers into the AssignTokenToDataTemplate action method but I cannot get it to work?!

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass both values using the `routeValues` parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "ASSIGN",                             // linkText
    "AssignTokenToDataTemplate",          // actionName
    "HostHtmlTokenManager",               // controllerName
    new {                                 // routeValues
        htmlTokenId = item.Id, 
        htmlDataTemplateId = 1 
    }, 
    null                                  // htmlAttributes
)
```

Comment: I tried this and it's done the job!
Thanks guys for your help! :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
@Html.ActionLink("ASSIGN", "AssignTokenToDataTemplate", "HostHtmlTokenManager", 
new { htmlTokenId = item.Id , htmlDataTemplateId = 1 })
```

However you might want to consider using a model (a type of your own) to pass them together as one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include both parameters in the anonymous class:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ASSIGN", "AssignTokenToDataTemplate", "HostHtmlTokenManager", 
            null, new { htmlDataTemplateId = 1, htmlTokenId = item.Id })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
@Html.ActionLink("ASSIGN", "AssignTokenToDataTemplate", "HostHtmlTokenManager", 
new { htmlTokenId = item.Id, htmlDataTemplateId = 1 })
```

Matt

Comment: Not sure the route change will be needed

Comment: @DanielElliott You are correct, I wasn't thinking properly, it seems!