# Pass multiple values from a View to an Action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following piece of code and I have 3 questions related to it:

JScript in the view:

```
$('#page1').load('@Url.Action("QuestionList", "Tests", new { testId = Model.Test.ID , Page = 2 })');
```

Action in the Tests controller:

```
public ActionResult QuestionList(int testId, int Page)
    {
        // some meaningless operations here
        return PartialView("QuestionList", somevalue);
    }
```

(The partial view is also QuestionList - I tried with another name, just to be on the safe side - and it did not work again)

The questions:

1. When using only testId everything is fine. Now that I added Page the Action paramter Page is always null.
2. I created a model that was supposed to replace the two variables. The new model is always null.
3. The third question is not related to the title, but to the current problem - how can I pass a value from the view to the Url.Action method? I know that the method is server side and the view with the JScript is on the client, but with this last problem that I have to solve I just got lost.

I already checked threads like this one: [Pass multiple values from view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258698/passing-multiple-value-from-mvc3-view-to-an-actionmethod), but the proposed solution is actually my problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way the ajax tag is valid for my question as the load function is based on ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to examine your querystring in the request to your Server to make sure it is not being escaped?
It should be similar to

```
"/Tests/QuestionList?testId=1&Page=2"
```

My guess it is getting escaped:

```
"/Tests/QuestionList?testId=1&amp;Page=2"
```

If that is the problem, use the @Html.Raw() helper.  See [MVC3 Url.Action querystring generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872157/mvc3-url-action-querystring-generation) for the complete solution.

Comment: Actually that is the problem, now I saw it, but because it is a partial view the link cannot be easily seen. Thanks a lot, it was going to cost me a lot more time.

Answer (score 0):

First: how did you pass your model? I had a problem similar to yours, when using MVCContrib grid. I tried to send data such as column and order by instantiating a new object, but that didn't workout. Instead of passing a MVCContrib.Options object like  `@Url.Action("QuestionList", "Tests", new { testId = Model.Test.ID , Page = 2, options = new MVCContrib.Options() })`, I had to send the name of the class properties: `@Url.Action("QuestionList", "Tests", new { testId = Model.Test.ID , Page = 2, Column="xxx", Order=Ascending })` or something like that.

Also, you seem to be creating your link correctly. Just in case, put an "@" in front of `Page` to be sure, maybe it is a reserved word.